# how to set width swiper-slide in animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I used **swiperjs** in my project.

Define the scenario:
The swiper takes up half the screen.
I want `slidesPerView: 1.5` in the initial definition of the swiper.

from `position: absolute;` for **.swiper** and from `width: 400px !important;` for **.swiper slide** I have used it so that the slider is removed from the container and connected to the right wall.

Then, when the user scrolls and reaches the slider range, during a simple animation, the title should be deleted and the slider will take the whole page and the number of `slidesPerView: 3`

Now the problem is that:
when the user scrolls `swiperShowCase.passedParams.slidesPerView = 3` does not work.

Can you help me, why slidesPerView does not equal 3 when the user reaches the slider range.

```js
// Swiper ShowCase
var swiperShowCase = new Swiper(".SwiperShowCase", {
  slidesPerView: 1.5,
  spaceBetween: 15,
  loop: true,
  keyboard: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },
});

const target = document.getElementById("showCase");
window.onscroll = function() {
  const scrollPosition =
    window.pageYOffset ||
    document.documentElement.scrollTop ||
    document.body.scrollTop ||
    0;
  if (scrollPosition >= target.offsetTop) {
    target.classList.add("active");
    swiperShowCase.passedParams.slidesPerView = 3;
  }
};
```

```css
/* container  */
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1320px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: ". content .";
}

.container>* {
  grid-area: content;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 2560px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2300px 1fr;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) and (max-width: 2559px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1820px 1fr;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) and (max-width: 1919px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1330px 1fr;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1320px) and (max-width: 1439px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1310px 1fr;
  }
}

/* container  */


.section1{
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}
.showCase {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.1);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.showCase--content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.showCase--content::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.1);
}

.showCase--content::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.1);
}

.showCase--content .title {
  width: 35%;
  margin-inline-start: 14px;
}

.showCase--slider {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
}

.showCase .showCase--slider .swiper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.showCase .swiper-slide {
  width: 400px !important;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.showCase .swiper-slide>div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.showCase .swiper-slide>div>img.indicatorImage {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  transform: scale(1.05);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.showCase .swiper-slide>div:hover img.indicatorImage {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
  filter: grayscale(0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.showCase .swiper-slide>p {
  font-size: var(--txt18);
  line-height: var(--line-height140);
  color: var(--third-color);
}


/* showCase animation */
 @keyframes fadeIn-top {
   0%{
     opacity: 1;
     }
  100% {
      transform: translateY(-500%);
      opacity: 0;
      }
    }

   @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn-top {
      0%{
        opacity: 1;
       }

      100% {
         transform: translateY(-500%);
         opacity: 0;
        }
   }

.showCase.active .showCase--content .title {
  width: 0;
  animation: fadeIn-top 3s forwards;
}

.showCase.active .showCase--content .showCase--slider {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section class="section1" ></section>

<section class="showCase" id="showCase">
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <div class="showCase--content">
        <div class="title">
          <h3> Showcases</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="showCase--slider">
          <div class="swiper SwiperShowCase">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                1
                <div>
                  <img src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/nebula_brown.png" alt="" class="indicatorImage" />
                </div>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                2
                <div>
                  <img src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back05.jpg" alt="" class="indicatorImage" />
                </div>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                3
                <div>
                  <img src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back04.jpg" alt="" class="indicatorImage" />
                </div>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                4
                <div>
                  <img src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back07.jpg" alt="" class="indicatorImage" />
                </div>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                5
                <div>
                  <img src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back02.jpg" alt="" class="indicatorImage" />
                </div>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```